# ajax calls and append, cannot select appended content or do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've two problems with this code.

1 `$(container + ' meta[data-level="' + level + '"]').length == 0` is always zero
I know this because I create extra call `create_views(1);` which should not get added, but it gets appended anyhow.

2 dpUniSlider doesn't work as it doesn't see li created via ajax call. If I move it into success message it works fine, but outside function does not. Problem is if I include it inside ajax success it will get called several times as it is under a loop

```
//Show levels using ajax, before slider is activated

function create_views(level) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "actions.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: "show_level=" + level,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
      var view = '<li data-level="' + level + '">' + data + '</li>';
      var container = ".slides_container";
      if ($(container + ' meta[data-level="' + level + '"]').length == 0) {
        $(container).append(view);
      } else { //check if element exists, if yes overwrite it.
        //$(container + ' meta[data-level="' + level + '"]').replaceWith(view);
        alert("Exists");
      }
    }
  });
}
 //Loop through all levels and display views
 //level count can be rewritten to come from DB and not be hardcoded like now
var levels = 2;
for (var i = 1; i <= levels; i++) {
  create_views(i);
} // for loop
create_views(1); //test, delete this
 //Activate slide
var unislider = $(".slides_container").dpUniSlider({
  //loop: false,
  draggable: false
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For handling multiple parallel asynchronous ajax calls where you want to perform something after they have all completed, you could keep a counter and check in the success callback to see when the last ajax call has succeeded.

It would look like this:

```
$(function() {
    var TOTAL_TASKS = 2,
        completedTasks = 0;

    function performAjaxTask(taskNumber) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                // Process the data

                completedTasks++;

                if (completedTasks == TOTAL_TASKS) {
                    // Perform actions that need to wait until all
                    // ajax calls have returned successfully.
                }
            }
        });
    }

    for (var i = 1; i <= TOTAL_TASKS; i++) {
        performAjaxTask(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Or, if you prefer to not write all the cruft, use a library like async. https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: I actually thought about this way, but hoped there was a better way :)

Comment: @Sandro Dzneladze - I added a second answer that shows how this can be accomplished using jQuery deferred objects. No extra library is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use jQuery deferred objects for handling the multiple parallel asynchronous ajax calls where you want to perform something after they have all completed successfully.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var LEVELS = 2,
        $container = $('.slides_container'),
        deferreds = []; // This will hold the deferred objects.

    // This function returns a deferred object.
    function getViewAndReturnDeffered(level) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'actions.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: 'show_level=' + level,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                var $currentView = $container.find('[data-level="' + level + '"]'),
                    $newView = '<li data-level="' + level + '">' + data + '</li>';
                if ($currentView.length > 0) {
                    $currentView.replaceWith($newView);
                } else
                    $container.append($newView);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    for (var i = 1; i <= LEVELS; i++) {
        // Put the deferred objects in the array.
        deferreds.push(getViewAndReturnDeffered(i));
    }

    // The function passed to `.done()` will execute when all the deferred
    // objects have completed successfully.
    $.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function() {
        var unislider = $container.dpUniSlider({
            //loop: false,
            draggable: false
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `<meta></meta>` inside `.container`? Probably not. Use

```
$(container + ' li[data-level="' + level + '"]')
```

Comment: yes I figured it out this exact moment :) if ($(container + ' li[data-level="' + level + '"]').length == 0) {

Comment: the other problem remains though :S